# Is it possible to limit the controls/formatting allowed while editing in Google Docs?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to develop an academic papers repository system in which students can create/edit their docs. In this regard I NEED to take over the Docs Interface (e.g. a user CANNOT change font size). Digging into Docs (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs) I've not found anything that allow me to get that job done!!!

The user will log into my app (it doesn't matter if he/her has a Google Account), cause I want full control over the docs.

So, I need to create an app with those requirements. Is it possible with Google Docs ???

Best regards,
Romualdo Rubens de Freitas.

Comment: Can't control / disable the built-in formatting icons in Docs or any other Google Apps interface.

Answer (score 0):

As Bryan said in the comment, you can't disable the formatting tools... the best you could do is to write a script that continuously "reformats" your document, setting font styles, sizes and other format parameters to a value you choose.

This script could run on a timer to let it run periodically.  I've written such a script for spreadsheets to keep the presentation the way I want and it works nicely... I guess it will be a bit trickier in documents because there are a lot more format parameters but it should be possible.